# Auth0 Passwordless Authentication takes user to loop when they open login url from gmail on iOS

Tags: reactjs, auth0, okta

I am using Auth0 (okta) password less authentication for one of my app. User inputs their email and a code is sent to their email for authentication. However, I am facing a major issue on mobile devices. I send an email with a login button. When user clicks the login button from their iPhones it opens in app browser. They type in their email and to see the code they have to go back and this loop continues. What's the best possible solution here?